# Creating Elastic Sink Connector between Confluent.Cloud(Kafka) to Elastic Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, elastic-cloud, confluent-cloud

I am creating the sink connector between Confluent.Cloud(Kafka) and Elastic Cloud

The following details I have added there,

```
{
    "name": "ElasticsearchSinkConnector_1",
    "config": {
    "topics": "sinktest",
    "input.data.format": "AVRO",
    "connector.class": "ElasticsearchSink",
    "name": "ElasticsearchSinkConnector_1",
    "connection.url": "https://enterprise-search-deployment-327352.es.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243",
    "connection.username": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "connection.password": "******",
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "tasks.max": "1"
  }
}
```

But, Finally, I got the below error,

`Failed. Connector was unable to create the specified index. Please check your permissions and verify the configured elastic server is healthy`

For, elasticsearch, I have created the test account in Elastic.Cloud
https://enterprise-search-deployment-327352.es.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243

Can you help me to fix this problem?. Do I need to add any permission in Elastic cloud and confluent.cloud?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem before.
Be sure that your Confluent Cluster is in the same region (eastus2) as your Elastic Cloud.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).